# Find the area bounded by the curve $y^2=4ax$ and $x=a$

Tags: calculus, integration, area

Find the area bounded by the curve $y^2=4ax$ and $x=a$

My attempt:

Solving equations $y^2=4ax$ and $x=a$ we get $y=\pm 2a$

And the area $=\int y. dx$ 
Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always graph things to see what the region looks like. Using [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) for $a=1$ this looks like the following.

[image]

We want the area between the red curve and the blue line.

There are many methods. The most straight-forward is to find the integral
$$
\int_{0}^{a} \sqrt{4ax} \,\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
which will give you the top half of the region, and then double it to get the whole region. Thus
$$
\int_{0}^{a} \sqrt{4ax} \,\,\mathrm{d}x = 2\sqrt{a} \int_{0}^{a} x^{\frac{1}{2}} \,\,\mathrm{d}x = 2\sqrt{a} \cdot\Big[ \frac{2x^{3/2}}{3} \Big]_{x=0}^{x=a} = \frac{4}{3}\cdot a^{2}.
$$
This is the top half of the region, so the area of the whole region is
$$
\frac{8}{3}\cdot a^{2}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

If you swich both axsis you can figure out you can do like this:

$$Area = 4a^2-2\int _0^{2a}{y^2\over 4a}dy = 4a^2-2{y^3\over 12a}\Big|_0^{2a}$$ $$= 4a^2- 2{8a^3\over 12a}= 4a^2 -4a^2/3 =8a^2/3$$

Comment: how did you get the limits $0$ and $a$?

Comment: Just reflect everything across the line $y=x$.

Comment: the answer in my book is $\dfrac {8a^2}{3}$??

Answer (score 0):

Solving $y^2=4ax$ and $y=6a$ we get
$x=9a$ so our integral will be $2\int_{0}^{9a}\sqrt{4ax}dx$